# Can i use Selenium Javascript for applications developed in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, automation

My application was developed in Java. So now to test the application can I use selenium+Javascript?

Comment: Is the frontend of your application a web application? If yes then of course you can.

Answer (score 0):

**how different language can be used to write selenium code**

If you see how driver works,

[image]

It act as a intermediate between , client and browser.

So from code you call this API , and api sends instruction to driver, which talks to browser , browser send result to driver driver sends back to client through API.

> eg elem.click() tells the api to invoke the code for click () , the
> driver execute the code and sends command to browser to click, and
> browser returns status to driver and driver returns the status back to
> client through the API

So you can use any selenium language binding methods , what it does is it just call the API of the driver behind the screen.

so you can use any language , the libraries in each language has code to talk to this api .

## Hence it doesn't matter what language you use as long as it is a webapp